# Insert php SimpleXMLElement to the MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, mongoid, simplexml

I'm using MongoDB(version 2.4.1) for storing information from XML files. During XML parsing process I create SimpleXMLElement for each item description. Here is the code for inserting new document:

```
$response = $collection->insert($object, array('safe'=>true, 'fsync'=> true)),
```

where $object has SimpleXMLElement type.

The problem is that I need to get id of the inserted document, but when I try to get it after insert operation it returns NULL:

```
$response = $collection->insert($object, array('safe'=>true, 'fsync'=> true)),
die(var_dump($object));
```

Is it an expected behavior for 'insert' operation?

Comment: How do you expect the PHP driver to insert this object? Or rather how do you expect it to work? I would say this is very expected

Comment: @Sammaye Actually, I would expect the `_id` property of `$object` to be set to a new `MongoId` instance, but I've not used the PHP MongoDB driver for other than very simple objects. Any reason it shouldn't work that I'm missing? :)

Comment: because it is a `SimpleXMLElement` object?

Comment: @Sammaye I expect, that '_id' field will contain MongoId object. When I pass array or object of stdClass to the insert() function everything works fine.

Comment: @Sammaye You may be right, in that case `$response` should contain an error that explains the problem.

Comment: stdclass is different, that will work because of what it is, SimpleXMLElement is not an object that will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted `stdclass` does work and the driver does successfully set the `_id` field on the object. This is because `stdclass` is analogous to an associative array and it's properties are able to be set publicly just like one.

`SimpleXMLElement` is not actually an object, as noted in the comments:

> What makes SimpleXMLElement tricky to work with is that it feels and behaves like an object, but is actually a system RESOURCE,  (specifically a libxml resource).

http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php

Further on in the comment:

> That's why you can't store a SimpleXMLElement to $_SESSION or perform straight comparison operations on node values without first casting them to some type of object.  $_SESSION expects to store 'an object' and comparison operators expect to compare 2 'objects' and SimpleXMLElements are not objects.

As such with this in mind I believe you require to cast the `SimpleXMLElement` is an object, from a resource, before it will work. However, even with this it will be tricky for the driver to understand how exactly to insert the object if it is not a `stdclass` or something easily serializable.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your own [MongoID](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) for the _id field in the PHP code. When you create a new MongoID object, it uses the same algorithm the database would be using to generate an ID, so it isn't better or worse than letting mongodb generate it (only difference: the bytes 4-6 are the machine-identifier of the machine which runs the PHP stack, not the one which runs the database). But when you generate the _id In the PHP code, you have the advantage that it is known in PHP without having to query the database for the value it generated.

Comment: I belive the ObjectId will be formed client side even if you do not enter one yourself, you do not wait for a response from the database as to what the objectid was